# How to query with multiple fields in IN clause?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to query a table with multiple combined fields in an `IN` clause.

Example: find all records with "john doe" and "marc smith", but ignore all other persons..

```
SELECT * FROM persons 
WHERE firstname IN ('john', 'marc')
   AND lastname IN ('doe', 'smith');
```

But I don't want to find `jane;doe` for example. But how can I combine multiple columns inside the IN clause?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM persons
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) IN ('john doe', 'marc smith')
  AND lastname <> 'doe';

Comment: I thought about this, but I would want to query for a few thousands of firstname+lastname combinations, on large tables with million of rows. Data increasing by time. So this might not be an option due to performance reasons.

Comment: You might combine both queries, using your `IN(..) AND IN(..)` as subquery, that reduces the set to be processed by the `WHERE CONCAT(..)`

Answer (score 1):

I discovered mysql supports this out of the box:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE (firstname, lastname) IN (('john', 'doe'), ('marc', 'smith'));
```

Comment: That was the first thing that I thought of but you stated yourself that there're thousands of combinations and they increase by time. Not really easy to maintain.

Comment: If the list gets very long, you might exceed `range_optimizer_max_mem_size`  and then MySQL will give up and do a table-scan. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-optimization-memory-use

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating a sort of lookup table that contains the first- and lastname combinations you're interested in.
Then query something like this:

```
SELECT persons.*
FROM   persons
JOIN   my_lookup
  ON   persons.firstname = my_lookup.firstname
 AND   persons.lastname = my_lookup.lastname;
```

In order to speed up the process, I would create a unique index on the first/lastname within that lookup table.

Comment: You can also use `USING (firstname, lastname)` as the join condition given the column names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the above concat function which would help you to eliminate different combination of name and surname.
Hope this helps !!!!

```
 select * from persons where CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) in ("john doe","marc smith");
```

Comment: This is not reliable because it would treat these tuples as the same: ("grace murray" "hopper") and ("grace" "murray hopper").

Comment: @BillKarwin cannot understand the question you raised any example if you could provided